# c++ Makefile with external h and o files

Tags: c++, makefile

I have project files and I need to use an external test file named `TestSuite1.cpp` that includes an external header file `SignalMasker.h` (Was given it and it's object file SignalMasker.o) and my main header file `uthreads.h`.

I'm still getting undefined refrences such as:

```
TestSuite1.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::~SignalMasker()'
```

This means my Makefile isn't including the `SignalMasker.o` file that resides in the same directory.

This is my Makefile:

```
CC = g++
FLAGS = -Wall -g 

OBJECTS = uthreads.o Thread.o Scheduler.o SchedulerStarter.o TestSuite1.o

.PHONY :  clean


all: test1

test1: $(OBJECTS)
    g++  $(FLAGS) $(OBJECTS) SignalMasker.o -L . -o test1


TestSuite1.o  : TestSuite1.cpp SignalMasker.h uthreads.h
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) TestSuite1.cpp

uthreads.o  : uthreads.cpp uthreads.h SchedulerStarter.h Scheduler.h Thread.h
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) uthreads.cpp 

Scheduler.o  : Scheduler.cpp Scheduler.h Thread.h
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) Scheduler.cpp 

SchedulerStarter.o  : SchedulerStarter.cpp SchedulerStarter.h Scheduler.h
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) SchedulerStarter.cpp 

Thread.o  : Thread.cpp Thread.h uthreads.h translateAdd.h
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) Thread.cpp 

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS) *~
```

And now I'm getting:

```
~/Desktop/tests$ make
g++  -Wall -g  uthreads.o Thread.o Scheduler.o SchedulerStarter.o TestSuite1.o SignalMasker.o -L . -o test1 
/usr/bin/ld: error: SignalMasker.o: incompatible target
TestSuite1.cpp:36: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::SignalMasker(int)'
TestSuite1.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::~SignalMasker()'
TestSuite1.cpp:63: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::~SignalMasker()'
TestSuite1.cpp:68: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::SignalMasker(int)'
TestSuite1.cpp:111: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::~SignalMasker()'
TestSuite1.cpp:111: error: undefined reference to 'SignalMasker::~SignalMasker()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**EDIT:**
 I'm now pondering with the idea that maybe *incompatible target* means they compiled it under 64bit. My machine is 32bit

Comment: Are you sure there is a file `/home/tom/Desktop/tests/SignalMasker.o`?

Comment: @honk now there is I accidently deleted it but still getting undefined refrences

Comment: Did you define the destructor, as opposed to just declaring it? Happens to me occasionally...

Comment: @dascandy it's been given by our uni. people are using it so it's not a problem in the .o file. Notice I now added the full errors

Comment: @dascandy I'm now pondering with the idea that maybe `incomplete target` means they compiled it under 64bit. My machine is 32bit

Comment: @Tom That sounds entirely plausible.

Comment: @Tom, yes, "incompatible target" means stop looking at the errors below it. Did they compile it for X86, X64 or (say) Sparc? You can find out with `objdump`

Answer (score 0):

you are missing rule to compile SignalMasker.cpp in your makefile. you have to write a rule, the same way you have written for 
SchedulerStarter.o, Thread.o

SignalMasker.o  : SignalMasker.cpp SignalMasker.h
    $(CC) -c $(FLAGS) SignalMasker.cpp

This will ensure the SignalMasker.o is generated with the same compilation flags that you build other objects. It will eliminate incompatibility issues in case of 32-bit/ 64-bit variants.

if you are copying this SignalMasker.o from elsewhere, check the compilation flags used for generating the object. Use the same flags in your makefile.